# error when running Set-SPProfileLeader in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, service-application

I want to manually set my organization's leader in SharePoint, using the following script from [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh393963.aspx). I modified the script to have the correct user profile service application proxy ID, and the correct username.

```
$upaProxy = Get-SPServiceApplicationProxy 1232b6f7-b9ff-99ad-0cd0-fg1g67h981aq
Add-SPProfileLeader -ProfileServiceApplicationProxy $upaProxy -Name "contoso\janedow"
```

Seems simple enough, but when I run the script I get an error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** This turns out to have been a permissions issue. Once I logged in under an account with higher permissions, the script in my post ran successfully.

Comment: is contoso\janedow right? fake users are typically janedoe.

Comment: @PirateEric The TechNet article used janedow, for whatever reason. As stated, I changed it for use within my organization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turns out to have been a permissions issue. Once I logged in under an account with higher permissions, the script in my post ran successfully.

Edit: To clarify, the problem wasn't the level of SharePoint permissions, but rather network or Active Directory permissions.

Answer (score 1):

LCountee, you wrote that you needed an account with higher permissions. What exact permissions are we talking about? I tried the same with a dedicated Farm Administrator account as well as with my Domain Administrator account that is member of Farm Administrators. I still get the object reference error/null reference exception for both the following commands:

```
Get-SPProfileLeader -ProfileServiceApplicationProxy $upap
Add-SPProfileLeader -ProfileServiceApplicationProxy $upap -Name domain\coleader
```

My $upap variable fully returns

```
Name                 Type                 Id
----                 ----                 --
Benutzerprofildie... Benutzerprofildie... 2106980f-ebff-4a58-82a3-15dc293d0372
```

where "Benutzerprofildienst-Anwendung(sproxy)" means "User Profile Application (Proxy)"

Any idea what could be wrong instead of the permissions?

Comment: The problem wasn't the level of SharePoint permissions, but rather network permissions. I think the account I originally used either wasn't a domain admin or didn't have enough Active Directory privileges. Also make sure you are running PowerShell as an administrator.

Comment: @LCountee, thank you for your answer. This is what I don't understand - I ran everything either as a domain or farm administrator; the PowerShell too and from the server directly. It doesn't work nonetheless. I work with SharePoint Server version 14.0.6029.1000 and 14.0.6106.5001 to some extent.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. See [How do I ask questions here?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask) for further help.

Comment: It is no new question, since this one here is not really solved. I have the exact some problem, the same symptom. Even if there are more than one solution, they are still to the same question.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have any further insight. I would recommend posting a new question as @SPDoctor suggests. Best of luck to you.

Comment: Sebastian, the "Your Answer" panel is intended for actual answers. If you want to comment or expand on the existing question you should use either comment on the original question or, if needed, edit the original question. I understand that the system only gives you limited priviledges initially, but these options will open up as you gain some reputation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this post for a detailed understanding?

http://www.harbar.net/archive/2011/07/06/329.aspx

Comment: I have read that post. It does not help with the error I'm getting.